# How to make an object from result of a Postgres query in an optimize or fastest way using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reduce, spread

ex:

```
arr =   | tCount     |system | atyId| aVersion|
        |:-----------|:------|:-----|:--------|
        | 12         |1001   |a001  |11       |
        | 12         |1001   |a002  |12       |
        | 12         |1002   |a003  |13       |
        | 12         |1001   |a004  |14       |
```

```
response = [ {
                 system: '1001',
                 data:  [
                          { 
                            atyId: 'a001  ',
                            aVersion: '11'
                           } ,
                          { 
                            atyId: 'a002  ',
                            aVersion: '12'
                           } ,
                           { 
                            atyId: 'a004  ',
                            aVersion: '14'
                           } 
                        ]
               },
              {
                 system: '1003',
                 data:  [
                          { 
                            atyId: 'a003  ',
                            aVersion: '13'
                           } 
                         ]
              }
         ]
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: O(n) can indexing improve the actual big-O time-complexity, or does it only reduce the entire query time by some constant factor?